# Grails REST CRUD Controller Methods

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I am pretty new to Grails, though I do have a lot of experience developing webapplications using other mvc frameworks in different languages (Perl, Python, Ruby).

I am trying to understand the implications of CRUD in grails.

Basically Grails creates by default for a create function the following two methods:

create, which is used to display the form to create
save, which is used to save the posted form

Now coming from different frameworks I am used to having just one method for create:

create, this function will display the form if the request method is GET and save the form if the request method is POST, which seems to be the prefered way of most frameworks?!?!?

Why did Grails go the route of having completely different methods for this functionality?  I know I can change it by hand, but what would be the implications of doing this?  What will I loose, what will I gain.

I know this is not a very specific question and I sure do not want to start a flame war, but I want to understand why to choose one way of the other ...

Thanks in advance for your ansers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 8):

When you generate a controller, it uses some default templates with {index, list, create, save, show, edit, update, delete} actions.  This is only a starting point, or used for reference.

What I typically do for public facing apps is setup URL mappings that handle routing based on HTTP methods. See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#mappingHTTP for details.

Basically, this lets you do something like:

```
static mappings = {
   "/product/$id"(controller:"product") {
       action = [GET:"show", PUT:"update", DELETE:"delete", POST:"save"]
   }
}
```

In a controller, the actions should be separate as they serve different purposes.  Grails lets you setup URL Mappings to handle HTTP method routing.

Comment: This is a nice Idea, but how do you differ between show, which will show the requested object and showing the editable version of that object, meaning a form with all the editable fields?

Comment: Grails as you noted, generates 2 different controller actions for one for showing the resource 'show' and one for showing the edit form for that resource 'edit' both using the HTTP GET method.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from combining the two in the show view.

Comment: Where is it documented? I mean the `[method: "action"]` part

Comment: The documentation has been updated - you can find it here for grails 2.4.4 http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/theWebLayer.html#7.4.7 Mapping to HTTP methods

Answer (score 3):

The code generated by the `generate-controller` and `generate-all` is just a convenience and a suggestion of what to do. It's generated into your application though, so edit it as needed, or write everything from scratch if you prefer.

The alternative to a `create` action that accepts GET requests and just creates a new instance and renders the GSP to create an instance, plus a `save` action that only accepts POST requests and does the actual creation if the instance is a single `create` method that does both:

```
def create() {
   if (request.post) {
      // persist the new instance
   }
   else {
      // render the GSP
   }
}
```

This requires explicit logic to determine what to do, which clutters the code. The approach that Grails takes is cleaner since each action is more focused and only does one thing. This has an added benefit of making testing easier.

If you find that there ends up being shared logic between the two actions, you can always refactor that into private methods that both call.

Comment: Yes I did understand that, but the question is, what do I loose if I do it that way, besides code beeing a little more cluttered, which can also be fixed.
Especially looking toward using javascript libraries like kind ofBackbone.js or ExtJS, which seem to be using the get/post methodology ...
The downside of having seperate methods create/save is also that you have to disallow GET requests somehow to the save action ...

Comment: Disallowing GET requests to the `save` action is a security precaution. There have been cases where applications that allowed deletes via GET were crawled by search engines and data was lost.

Comment: Not only that, but with prefetching url's in modern browsers you get some odd behaviour ...